# sorting based on column stored as value in another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I have this requirement
my input table:

```
ID  FI  SERIAL sortorder
1   5    3     id,fi,serial
4   2    2     id,fi,serial
3   2    7     id,fi,serial
```

so what I want really is, to read the 'sortorder' column to check what is the criteria to sort and then sort what ever key word i find there. Something like

```
select * from my_table order by (substring(sortorder,1))
```

it's just an example. I know that query doesn't make sense. I want to replace my order by clause with `id,fi,serial` So when I execute the query on the database it takes these values as column names and sorts it. Something like this:

```
select * from my_table order by id,fi,serial
```

Is it even possible or is there any other way to approach this?

Comment: The concept you want to search on here at SO and in the Postgres documentation is "dynamic sql".

Comment: that's a bad design. you're violating 1NF

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What if there is a different "sort order" defined for every row of the table?

Comment: You could of course write a small program in your language of choice (dynamic sql or other) which first reads the sortorder field and then creates a second query using it for your query.

Comment: And yes, you'll have to use a top 1 sortorder so that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @carra--Yes, i am trying that approach only, can you provide any pointers how can i achieve that,

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name--sort order will be same for all the rows in a table, though i have another requirement something like that, but if i can tackle this one then i might try something for that awkward scenrio too

Comment: In general, do a top 1 to get you order by and put it in a string. Lookup postgress dynamic sql to see how you can build your select * order by + orderstring.

Comment: If the sort order is the same for all rows, then why repeat that information for each and every row?

Answer (score 0):

ok, i tried this query, but have not tested it thoroughly,

```
select * from my_table order by case when position('id' in sortorder) > 0 then id end,
case when position('fi' in sortorder) > 0 then fi end,
case when position('serial' in sortorder) > 0 then serial end
```

i am getting the desired output, can some one provide some other solution, also i want to use this query in procedure(function in postgres)..how can i wrap this in query.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly too, but in the standard SQL syntax one could use 3x2 unions.

```
select id as K1, fi as K2, serial as K3, *
from my_table
where sortorder = 'id,fi,serial'
union
select fi as K1, id as K2, serial as K3, *
from my_table
where sortorder = 'fi,id,serial'
union
...
order by K1, K2, K3
```

Or something like

```
select (case sortorder
        when 'id,fi,serial' then id * 1000000 + fi * 1000 + serial
        when ...
        end) as K123, serial as K3, *
from my_table
order by K123
```